# How many digits to code an octet?

Tags: binary

1. How many digits if base ten?
2. How many digits if base eight?

I know an Octet is a unit consisting of eight bits, up to 255.  However I do not understand how it would change if it was in base ten/base eight.

Comment: An octet is 8 bits, a byte if you prefere. What you are refering to is the octal base (= base 8), which is something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent any octet with 3 digits in decimal(base 10), and also, with 3 digits in octal (base 8).

in that case the answer would be

1. 3  (0-255)
2. 3  (0-377)

in base16 (eg hex) you can represent an octet with 2 digits (00 - FF)

an octet is 8 bits of information.

Comment: What is the default base of an octet?  If octet is ten bits in base ten, then would it still be considered an octet?

Comment: I believe I found your answer. if so, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

An octet is 8 bits (oct prefix means 8), so you have `2^8 = 256` possible bit patterns, or a decimal range of `0..255`.  This requires 2 hexadecimal or 3 decimal digits, but note that you are not using the full 3 decimal digits (sometimes called 2.5 digits).  And since octal (base-8) representation is `2^3 = 8` possible bit patterns, you need 3 octal digits.

- base-2, 8 binary digits, `0..11111111b`
- base-8, 3 octal digits, `0..377`
- base-10, 3 decimal digits, `0..255`
- base-16, 2 hexadecimal digits, `0..FF`